# Get entry field data via a plugin. ( For specific image assets )

Tags: plugin-development, assets

I've got an asset field on a channel entry called "thumbnail". I'm using it to return a singular image, specifically for an image transform called "thumb". Looks a little like this:

```
{{ entry.thumbnail.first().getUrl('thumb') }}
```

This works fine. But I'd like to get the same information/url using a plugin (so I can perform some colour validation and other checks via PHP).

Can anyone share some wisdom on how best to approach this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you already have the entry (see [Working with Elements](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) for info about how to do that), you can interact with it exactly the same way you do in your templates - just with PHP syntax instead of Twig.

```php
$asset = $entry->thumbnail->first();

if ($asset)
{
    $url = $asset->getUrl('thumb');
}
```

Though the transform won’t necessarily be available yet, since getUrl() will not generate transforms that don’t already exist by default.

That behavior can be customized with the [generateTransformsBeforePageLoad](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#generateTransformsBeforePageLoad) config setting though, and lucky for you, you can even override the actual config value from PHP before calling getUrl(), using [ConfigService::set()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/ConfigService#set-detail):

```php
craft()->config->set('generateTransformsBeforePageLoad', true);
$url = $asset->getUrl('thumb');
```